# monitoring top processes for retrospective troubleshooting on linux

Tags: linux, system-monitoring

I often have trouble with servers which become inaccessible due to high CPU utilization which then have to be restarted or killed.

I use collectd and graphite for stats collection but I have not found a way of getting such information into a time series db.

Is there a tool or a method of monitoring top processes in retrospect?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [netdata](https://my-netdata.io) and setting the time window to a longer period. I believe it defaults to the last hour, but I set my servers to maintain 12 hours of data.

The main metric you can use is CPU% per application group versus time:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've heard about netdata but never came around to trying it. I will take a look at how feasible it will be to install on our systems.